# If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n\ $ is a conditionally convergent series, then is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n+a_{n+1}|\ $ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n\ $ is a [conditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20series%20or,it%20does%20not%20converge%20absolutely.) series, then is the sum of the average of consecutive terms necessarily convergent?

In other words, is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n+a_{n+1}|\ $ convergent?

For the most standard example, the alternating harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\over n+1},$ we get that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n+a_{n+1}|\ $ is half the sum of the reciprocal triangular numbers, which does converge.

But does every conditionally convergent (but not necessarily alternating sign) series have this property, or is there one that diverges?

I feel like I'm missing some obvious triangle inequality trick, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. Take your example, and interweave it with the all-zero sequence:
$$
a_{n} = \begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{n+1} &\text{ if } n \text{ even}\\
0 &\text{ if } n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of that *at all*.

Comment: There might be more natural/less contrived, but it does the job. :)

Comment: Note that this generalizes pretty broadly; the interwoven terms could e.g. be terms of an absolutely convergent series rather than zero, and they can be laid in whatever pattern is desired, to show that the answer is the same for whatever finite subsequence you might choose to average over.

Comment: @Steven I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @AdamRubinson The counter example can be generalized to 3, or any fixed number of terms, instead of two consecutive; and some other patterns than just consecutive terms as well.

Comment: Yeah but can't the counter-example be generalised by using $0$'s as the interwoven terms? Why do we need the interwoven terms to be terms in a conditionally convergent series?

Comment: Oh, that'd just be useful if you require extra conditions (e.g., non-zero terms) -- there'd still be counterexamples even then.

Comment: Yeah sure. I see.